# 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object' at compile time

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-runtime, monogame

I made a game and released it. I want to make a Lite version of the game so I decided to make a 2nd project in my solution named 'myGameLite'.
It's a Xaml/Monogame project like the original one.

I deleted all the *.cs and *.xaml files of the Lite project and added all the files of the original project as a link. Now when I try to build the Lite project, I get the next error:

> Error 1   Object reference not set to an instance of an
>   object.   RockTheBlockLite.WinRT

Definitely looks like a NullReferenceException but I've never seen it in compile time.

I doublechecked all values in my project properties and in the appxmanifest but I can't find anything wrong in there.
The original project still compiles.

Anyone got an idea how I can get this solved?

Comment: That's a tricky one to track down. Can you post a screenshot of the solution explorer so we can see what files are added to the 'Lite' project? My thinking is that you've added or removed something that you shouldn't have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed it. It was kinda hard for anyone to figure out without seeing the actual solution.

The App.xaml was also added as link but it wasn't set up as ApplicationDefinition . So the whole project didn't have an ApplicationDefinition which is why  this occured.

I guess a better error would've been: 'No application definition found' instead of showing a NullReferenceException but at least it's solved and it's on SO now in case others get this problem too :)